# Generic method to register/unregister event handler

Tags: c#, generics

I try to figure out a way to keep my event registration and un-registration in sync from my initialization and cleanup. 
What I want is to be able to call a generic method to register or unregister an event and only pass a Boolean to give the operation.

I don't want to use with Window, but that was the for an easy sample.

```
class EventSample
{
    private Window myWindow;

    public EventSample(Window window)
    {
        myWindow = window;
        InitEvent(true);
    }

    ~EventSample()
    {
        InitEvent(false);
    }

    private void InitEvent(bool register)
    {
        // I want a generic similar to that
        RegisterEvent(register, myWindow.Activated, MyWindow_Activated);
        RegisterEvent(register,myWindow.Closed , MyWindow_Closed);
        RegisterEvent(register, myWindow.Closing ,MyWindow_Closing);
    }



    private void MyWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void MyWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void MyWindow_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it WPF? How `RegisterEvent` method looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problems with cleanup methods. I have solved this by keeping a list of actions to execute when disposing the window or control.

Something like this:

```
this.RegisterEvent
    ( () => this.Event += handler
    , () => this.Event -= handler
    );
```

The `RegisterEvent` executes (delayed in my case) the event attachment:

```
private List<Action> unregisterEvents = new List<Action>();

private void RegisterEvent(Action registerAction, Action unregisterAction)
{
    registerAction.Invoke();

    unregisterEvents.Add(unregisterAction);
}
```

On dispose, just walk over the unregister events:

```
foreach (Action a in unregisterEvents)
{
    a.Invoke();
}
```